# How to add Javac option in maven build process?

Tags: java, maven, build, jar, javac

I want to compile my maven project with the javac options. How to include this javac option in the maven compilation process?

Comment: Configure the compiler maven plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<compilerArgs>` tag. For example:

```
<compilerArgs>
  <arg>-Xmaxerrs</arg>
  <arg>1000</arg>
  <arg>-Xlint</arg>
  <arg>-J-Duser.language=en_us</arg>
</compilerArgs>
```

Here you can find the Maven documentation: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs